# Inconsistent parentheses around the year in IEEE-style bibolography (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` (with IEEE style) for my dissertation and I noted an inconsistency when references were printed out within the bibliography.

[image]

As shown, the year in the first reference is in parantheses, while the other is not.

Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bibstyle=ieee, maxcitenames=2, mincitenames=1, maxbibnames=999999, style=numeric-comp,  sorting=none, natbib=true, doi=false,isbn=false,url=true,eprint=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{tommasel2016personality,
    title={Personality-aware followee recommendation algorithms: An empirical analysis},
    author={Tommasel, Antonela and Corbellini, Alejandro and Godoy, Daniela and Schiaffino, Silvia},
    journal={Engineering Applications of Artificial Intelligence},
    volume={51},
    pages={24--36},
    year={2016},
    publisher={Elsevier},
    doi = {10.1016/j.engappai.2016.01.016}
}

@inproceedings{song2010feature,
    title={Feature selection using principal component analysis},
    author={Song, Fengxi and Guo, Zhongwei and Mei, Dayong},
    booktitle={2010 international conference on system science, engineering design and manufacturing informatization},
    volume={1},
    pages={27--30},
    year={2010},
    organization={IEEE}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
    
    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I noted that IEEE style references do without the parentheses, and I would like to conform with such standard. How should I deal with this inconsistency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two style declarations and the second one overrides the first.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{tommasel2016personality,
    title={Personality-aware followee recommendation algorithms: An empirical analysis},
    author={Tommasel, Antonela and Corbellini, Alejandro and Godoy, Daniela and Schiaffino, Silvia},
    journal={Engineering Applications of Artificial Intelligence},
    volume={51},
    pages={24--36},
    year={2016},
    publisher={Elsevier},
    doi = {10.1016/j.engappai.2016.01.016}
}

@inproceedings{song2010feature,
    title={Feature selection using principal component analysis},
    author={Song, Fengxi and Guo, Zhongwei and Mei, Dayong},
    booktitle={2010 international conference on system science, engineering design and manufacturing informatization},
    volume={1},
    pages={27--30},
    year={2010},
    organization={IEEE}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  style=ieee,
  maxcitenames=2,
  mincitenames=1,
  maxbibnames=999999,
  sorting=none,
  natbib=true,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false,
  url=true,
  eprint=false,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
    
    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]